# How do I use CSS to alternate css styles on img tags?

Tags: javascript, html, css, json, image

I'm trying to style a Chat Transcript window. Data coming from a json file. I'm able to get the output fine, but I want to alternate the alignment on the chat blocks.  E.g. User1 message displays as "IMG" - "MESSAGE" User2 as "MESSAGE" - "IMG".
I've tried using nth-child and nth-of-type and neither give the result i'm looking for.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```html
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="grid-container">
       <div class="grid-item">CHAT TRANSCRIPT</div>
       <div class="grid-item" id="chatDate"></div>
   </div>
   <div id="newData"></div>
</div>
```

Here's the JS

```js
fetch(url)
    .then(function(response) {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(function(data) {
      const myData = data.data;
      const d = new Date(myData.conversationDate);
      document.getElementById('chatDate').innerHTML = moment(d).format('dddd, MMMM DD, YYYY');
      let html = '';
      for (i = 0; i < myData.messages.length; i++) {
        const messageTime = new Date(myData.messages[i].timestamp);
        html += `
        <div class="container">
            <img src="${myData.messages[i].image}">
            <div >
                <a href="">${myData.messages[i].message}</a><br />
                ${myData.messages[i].username} ${moment(messageTime).format('h:mm a')}
            </div>
        </div>
        `;
        document.getElementById('newData').innerHTML = html;
      // document.getElementById("userImage").src = myData.messages[i].image;
      // document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = myData.messages[i].message;
      }
    });
```

Here's the css

```css
.grid-container {
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  border:1px solid green;
  grid-column-gap: 100px;
}
.grid-item {
  border:1px solid red;
}
#chatDate {
  font-family:RobotoReg;
  size:18px;
  color:#999;
  text-align:right;
}
.wrapper {
    border:1px solid #000;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px grey;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 500px;
    padding:20px;
    background-color:#fff;
}
.container {
  /* border: 2px solid #dedede; */
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px grey;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px 0;
}
.chatBlock {
  background-color:#999;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color:#000;
}
  .container a:focus {
    border-color: #ccc;
    background-color: #ddd;
    box-shadow: none;
  }
  /* Style images */
  img {
    border-radius: 50px;
    max-width: 60px;
    margin-left:0px;
    margin-right:0;
  }
  img:nth-of-type(odd) {
    border:1px soolid red;
    float:left;
    margin-right: 20px;
  }
  img:nth-of-type(even) {
     float: right;
    margin-left: 20px;
  }

/* Clear floats */
  .container::after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: table;
  }
```

```html
    <div id="newData">
        <div class="container">
            <img src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/2.jpg">
            <div class="item">
                <a href="">Hi Charlie! It was good meeting you for coffee the other day, I would love to talk more about your autonomous car start up! Here's my email: webtrabel@email.com</a><br>
                Mygel van Trabel 1:41 pm
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="container">
            <img src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/4.jpg">
            <div class="item">
                <a href="">Thanks, Mygel! It was a pleasure chatting with you as well. You may also be interested in learning more about my new cryptocurrency start up, Goldhill LLC!</a><br>
                Charlie Hemn 1:46 pm
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="container">
            <img src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/2.jpg">
            <div class="item">
                <a href="">I recently started a cryptocurrency start up as well! I'll definitely read through the whitepaper posted on the Goldhill website and get back to you!</a><br>
                Mygel van Trabel 1:50 pm
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="container">
            <img src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/4.jpg">
            <div class="item">
                <a href="">Sounds good to me! Looking forward to hearing from you - Charlie.</a><br>
                Charlie Hemn 2:03 pm
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Can you provide the output html, as it renders after the js has run? Several messages and their container would be enough.

Comment: Added rendered HTML to post.

Comment: Isn't nth-of-type only for siblings?  So maybe: `div:nth-of-type(odd) img { }`

Comment: GOT IT!  Ended up being div.container:nth-of-type(odd) img
Thanks @John-Hascall!!